# How to configure multi-channel sound card with raspbian stretch

Tags: audio

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a Native Instruments Audio 8 DJ sound card which I want to work with Reaper. Thing is that if I open Reaper I get the error message: ALSA: error setting input device format bits.

If I open Patchage I see Reaper with 6 out but only two system outputs. What do I do wrong?

I want to use reaper because I want to have it start up automatically and play 5 mono tracks via 5 outs on my sound card.

I have disabled my onboard sound card so my devices look like this:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Audio8DJ ]: snd-usb-caiaq - Audio 8 DJ
Native Instruments Audio 8 DJ (usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2)

This is the module I'm using:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/asound/modules
0 snd_usb_caiaq

This is how my asound.conf in the etc folder looks:

```
pcm.my_Audio_8-DJ_(Ch-A) { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:0,0,0"; }
pcm.my_Audio_8-DJ_(Ch-B) { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:0,0,1"; }
pcm.my_Audio_8-DJ_(Ch-C) { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:0,0,2"; }
pcm.my_Audio_8-DJ_(Ch-D) { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:0,0,3"; }
```

When I open Audacity I actually can select it. One comment though is that there is a remark that it's been done with Portaudio V19.6.0-devel revision. Is this maybe a workaround?